# cannot find sqlcmd in win server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

i am using Windows Server 2008.Where i couldn't get the sqlcmd running using cmd:
It says: 'sqlcmd' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: you mention Windows Server 2008, but not SQL Server 2008.  Is SQL Server on that box?  Did you search for sqlcmd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have SQL Server 2008 installed, then you will have to install SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack

Ie : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8824

Select the right version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Command Line Utilities
The SQLCMD utility allows users to connect to, send Transact-SQL batches from, and output rowset information from SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005, and SQL Server 2008 instances. The bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and a data file in a user-specified format. The bcp utility can be used to import large numbers of new rows into SQL Server tables or to export data out of tables into data files.

Note: This component requires both Windows Installer 4.5 and Microsoft SQL Server Native Client (which is another component available from this page).